# Extracting class inside a div returns None in Python Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests, webrequest

The snippet below does not really display the intended data as it returns None. Any idea and inputs as how to do it properly will be very helpful.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import request
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

url = "https://bscscan.com/block/9478762"
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"}

req = Request(url, headers=headers)
html = urlopen(req).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

blockheight = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'font-weight-sm-bold mr-2'})
print ("Block Height: ", blockheight)

blocktimestamp = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'far fa-clock small mr-1'})
print ("Timestamp ",blocktimestamp)

blocktransactions = soup.find('div', class_ = 'u-label u-label--value u-label--primary rounded my-1')
print ("Transactions ", blocktransactions)
```

Current Output:

```
    Block Height:   None
    Timestamp:      None
    Transactions:   None
```

Wanted Output:

```
    Block Height:   9478762
    Timestamp:      Jul-25-2021 11:43:52 PM +UTC
    Transactions:   223 -> transactions https://bscscan.com/txs?block=9478762
                    37 -> contract internal transactions https://bscscan.com/txsInternal?block=9478762
    Validated by:   0xb218c5d6af1f979ac42bc68d98a5a0d796c6ab01
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I hope this helps:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import request
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

url = "https://bscscan.com/block/9478762"
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"}

req = Request(url, headers=headers)
html = urlopen(req).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

blockheight = soup.find('span', attrs={'class': 'font-weight-sm-bold mr-2'}).contents[0]
print ("Block Height: ", str(blockheight).replace("\n", ""))

blocktimestamp = soup.find('i', attrs={'class': 'far fa-clock small mr-1'}).next_sibling
print ("Timestamp: ",str(blocktimestamp).replace("\n", ""))

blocktransactions = soup.find('a', class_ = 'u-label u-label--value u-label--primary rounded my-1').contents[0]
print ("Transactions: ", blocktransactions)
```

**Output:**

```
Block Height:   9478762
Timestamp:  2 hrs 35 mins ago (Jul-25-2021 11:43:52 PM +UTC) 
Transactions:  223 transactions
```

Comment: I managed to do some edits but i still lack the the data on the href part. I will wait though for more ideas to work into.

Comment: I managed to make the editing and presented the result the way I wanted it to be.